# Videos overlapping the "Add this" window in IE!

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a HTML simple page with a ADD THIS button (the share button actually) and some videos on it. My problem is that when I click on the SHARE button and a small window (a div) pop ups on the center of the browser screen which is keeps it position constant there.

When I scroll the window, this ADD THIS window gets overlapped by the videos on the page. This works good in Firefox but not in IE and Chrome.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #at16p, #atie6ifh
        {
            overflow-y: auto !important;
        }        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <a class="addthis_button" style="text-align: right;" href="http://addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;pub=xa-4ac61e0801642c41">
        <img src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-en.gif" width="125" height="16"
            alt="Bookmark and Share" style="border: 0" /></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pub=xa-4ac61e0801642c41"></script>

    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
    <center>
        <div id="divVideoDisplay" runat="server" style="width: 100%; padding-bottom: 20px;
            z-index: -10000; overflow: hidden;">
            <br />
            <h1>
                First Video</h1>
            <br />
            <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://www.videowebtown.com/community/newlightplayer/flvplayer.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fsq.txdnl.com%2Fvwt%2Fd%2Fa%2Fv%2Fi%2Fdavidmarsh98%2Fvideo%2F26198%2FFLV%2F98188.flv' style="z-index: -1;" 
                width='640' height='480' bgcolor='FFFFFF' border='1'>
                <param name='movie' value='http://www.videowebtown.com/community/newlightplayer/flvplayer.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fsq.txdnl.com%2Fvwt%2Fd%2Fa%2Fv%2Fi%2Fdavidmarsh98%2Fvideo%2F26198%2FFLV%2F98188.flv'/>
                <param name='bgcolor' value='FFFFFF'/>
                <param name='Windowless' value='true'/>
                <embed src='http://www.videowebtown.com/community/newlightplayer/flvplayer.swf?file=http%3A%2F%2Fsq.txdnl.com%2Fvwt%2Fd%2Fa%2Fv%2Fi%2Fdavidmarsh98%2Fvideo%2F26198%2FFLV%2F98188.flv'
                    quality='high' bgcolor='#ffffff' width='640' height='480' name='movie' allowscriptaccess='sameDomain'
                    type='application/x-shockwave-flash' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer'
                    border='1'>
            </object>
            <br>
            <b style="color: red">FREE</b> service provided by <a href='http://www.videowebtown.com'
                target='_new'><u>VideoWebTown.com</u></a>
            <br />
            <h1>
                Second Video</h1>
            <br />
            <object width="425" height="344" style="z-index: -1;" >
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rrrx9izp0Lc&hl=en_US&fs=1&">
                </param>
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                <param name='Windowless' value='true'/>
                <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rrrx9izp0Lc&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344">
        </embed>
            </object>
        </div>
    </center>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help/comments appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this code required

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

to be added to the object tag and also the `<embed>` tag required an attribute as `wmode="transparent"`.

i.e. `<embed wmode="transparent" ... />`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">`

This is a well-known bug in IE, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work in Chrome, so I'm hoping this will solve it for both browsers. Also, have you checked the Z-index just to be sure? (This doesn't matter for IE, but it might for Chrome)

Comment: I'd actually use opaque for the value. If the player had some transparent colors, the HTML behind it would be shown through (unless that is what you want, of course)

Comment: Well this worked for the first video in my code but not for the second one. :-(
Can't guess why is it so?